# Jsoup Issue scraping non-hardcoded data

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm trying to use Jsoup to gather wave height information from [Surfline.com](http://www.surfline.com/surf-report/folly-beach-pier-southside-southeast_5294/). I have the element I desire in the screenshot and the it's showing in the dev tools. When I scrape the site with Jsoup, the returned string includes everything seen in the dev tool but the "1-2ft" which is what I need. The site is Javascript heavy and I'm assuming that jsoup is snagging the html before the javascript actually runs (I have no clue really). Do I need to specifically tell jsoup to wait for the pageload or am I missing some other critical component?

[image: surfline.com]

This is the code I'm using.

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.surfline.com/surf-report/folly-beach-pier-southside-southeast_5294/").get();
    Elements content = doc.select("div[id=current-surf-range]");
    System.out.println(content);
```

and this is the output I'm seeing in my IDE

```
<div id="current-surf-range" style="font-size:21px;font-weight:bold;padding-top:7px; padding-bottom: 7px;"></div>
```

it seems really odd that the contents of the div wouldn't be returned with it. This is my first time using Jsoup and I tried to read through the docs as best I could but nothing seemed to touch on this particular issue. Any insight would be awesome and greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*What you see in the browser is not what necessarily you would get when download the page by URL with your HTTP library of a choice*. In fact, you should never expect them to be the same. In the modern web, webpages are quite dynamic and are loaded asynchronously involving multiple API calls to different resource providers and javascript being executed in the browser (which has the javascript engine).

What you get with `JSoup` in this case is the initial HTML that browser starts to form the page with. Then, there is a set of XHR calls to the *surfline API* that brings the data into the browser which then dynamically fills up different parts of the page, including the current surf range.

---

The simplest way to approach the problem is to switch to browser automation tool called [`selenium`](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/) which would fire up a real browser. You can then wait for the current surf range element to have a value and, if you wish to continue with `JSoup`, get the page source and feed it to `JSoup` for further parsing.

Another approach would involve looking into the requests that the page makes in the browser developer tools and then try to simulate these requests in your code, parsing the JSON responses and extracting the surf forecast data.